# Sharing uwp application

Tags: uwp, windows-dev-center

What is the proper way to share the UWP project for a job interview without revealing the code? The easiest solution might be putting the application on windows10 store, but I would like not to do that. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As an interviewer): Your interviewer is probably more interested in the code than in the product. Test tasks usually are useless in production anyway.

To answer your question:

Create a sideloadable appx package.

Right click on the project -> Store -> Create App Packages -> Don't publish to store.

Follow the wizard and it will build and create the app package folder inside your project folder. It will contain .appx package, your custom certificate, powershell script and dependencies folder.

Send this entire folder to the interviewer. Interviewer will need to run ps script to install your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick reply. I understand the interviewer should be more interested in the code itself, but lets assume I made my project for another client. It is obvious I will not send my interviewer the code, right? I'm a student, so my code isnt as valuable as it could be, but at the same time I dont want to seem to be an ignorant and dont know how to properly share my work.

Comment: Usually as an interviewer I expect to receive a cleaned up from binaries project folder that I can build and run myself. Usually in a form of a zip archive or any repository link.

Comment: Good way, can I private publish my app?

Comment: @lindexi yes you can private publish an app in the store and share the link it via email. If you search for the app in the store, nobody can find it, but it can only accessed via the URL generated by the store.

On the other hand as a student you have free access to github private repositories, that you can make use of and share.

Comment: @user3079834 Thx ,it help me .